# Can you unpickle a python user-defined class instance in c++?

Tags: python, c++, pickle

Given that in my python script i have a user defined class `item`, with properties `name: str` and `valid: bool`, and a corresponding class in my C++ program, is there any way i can unpickle a pickle file, pickled in python, that contains an instance of my python `item` class, in C++?

Comment: Can you post example code of what you've tried.

Comment: I don't know if what you are asking about is possible, but have you considered using a more language-neutral serialization like JSON or YAML (which are also fairly easy to use from Python)?

Comment: @ruhola, @fakdedad I have indeed considered these solutions. The example is so simple there is no code needed, still though i was wondering if i could use the `pickle` module instead of serializing my class instances to dictionaries and then JSON.